# Read From Text File

Tags: c#, asp.net, t-sql

I am reading from a text file in C# using a SQL statement. This is what I am using:

```
var strconn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + importFolder + ";Extended Properties=\"text;HDR=No;IMEX=1;FMT=Delimited\"";
var conn = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(strconn);
var da = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" + file + "]", conn);
```

This works fine, but it includes the blank lines at the bottom of the file. Is it possible to make it ignore or disregard the blank lines?

Thanks!

More code:

```
var importFolder = Path.GetDirectoryName(savedfile);
var file = Path.GetFileName(savedfile);

var strconn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + importFolder + ";Extended Properties=\"text;HDR=No;IMEX=1;FMT=Delimited\"";
var conn = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(strconn);
var da = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" + file + "]", conn);
da.Fill(Exceptions);
```

Comment: Is the contents of the file trusted? You might need to worry about SQL injection vulnerability?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I would create a new file from the old file using something like this (assuming the file is small enough to fit in memory):

```
var oldLines = File.ReadAllLines(file);
var newLines = oldLines.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrWhitespace(s));
File.WriteAllLines(newFileName, newLines);
```

EDIT:

I always forget about this newer method, which bypasses the "small enough to fit in memory" requirement:

```
var oldLines = File.ReadLines(file);
var newLines = oldLines.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrWhitespace(s));
File.WriteAllLines(newFileName, newLines);
```

ReadLines returns an `IEnumerable<string>`; it doesn't read the whole file into memory.

Comment: That's another way of doing it too.

Comment: Thanks! Does that mean I don't need the strconn, conn and da parts?

Comment: No, you still need all those parts, but you use them to read the new (temp?) file from which you have removed blank lines.

Comment: @phoog The IsNullorWhiteSpace takes out more whitespace than I want. Is it possible to just take out the whitespace just at the end of the file after all the records. So like I have all my records and then at the bottom of the test file when you scroll down there are line breaks that make space I need to get rid of. Thanks!

Comment: This should remove all blank lines from the file.  Do you have blank lines in the file that you want to leave in, because there are subsequent non-blank lines?

Comment: It writes to the temp file, etc. But it seems to do something to the format I have in the original file. The text file has several columns and my code checks hose columns for certain rules. After it writes to the temp file and tried to read it, it seems to not understand the format anymore. Anyway around that? Or is there a way without writing to a new file? Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps the text encoding is different in the two files.  Try comparing them in a text editor or a hex editor to see what has changed.  Or, if you have any column that always has data, you can try McKay's second answer: `WHERE [TheColumn] IS NOT NULL`

Comment: The lines.Where on the second line should be oldlines.Where, is that right? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" + file + "] where SomeImportantColumn is not null and SomeImportantColumn <> ''", conn);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
file.Trim()
// or
file.Trim('\r', '\n')
// or 
file.TrimEnd('\r', '\n')
```

All of those will remove empty lines at the end, but behave slightly differently in other ways.

Comment: Will not remove all blank lines.  Only the ones at the end.

Comment: @Fantius Or in the case of the first two, and at the beginning.

Comment: @McKay Thanks! Do I put the Trim at the end of the file in the Select? Like: "SELECT * FROM [" + file.Trim() + "]"

Comment: Yeah, that's one way to do it. Another way would be to assign it to a new variable `var trimmedFile = file.Trim()` and then use that in your select.

Comment: -1 How can this work?  The variable `file` is the name of the file, but the poster is looking to remove blank lines from the contents of the file.

Comment: @phoog I'm not sure that `file` is the name of the file. Based on what he was saying it appears as if `file` is the contents of the file. We'd need to see more code to be sure.

Comment: @McKay would `"SELECT * FROM [ " + file +  "]"` work if `file` held the contents of the file?  I don't think so.

Comment: @phoog It depends on whether there is only the name of the table in the file.

Comment: @McKay with the ODBC text driver, you use the file name as if it were the name of the table.  The extended properties in the code example show that the file is a delimited data file.

Comment: I added some more code. Don't know if it's enough. The Trim on file doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Correct, with the new code he edited in. This solution won't work.